# How to find 2nd and 3rd occurrence char(,) in column in redshift db?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In redshift i am using below code.but i am getting first special character position only.

**SELECT id,regexp_instr(id,',') ,regexp_instr(id,',',2)FROM test**

Comment: can you provide example of a record you're trying to parse?

Comment: My record like     5434980cd70ba0c37d0028, 544976cae79548b16810, 55afdbe672450000a01. So i want 1st,2nd,3rd position of (,) values .

Comment: Why do you want to find those positions? Is it to parse the individual elements from the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ultimately want the individual field values and not just the position of the commas you can use [SPLIT_PART](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select split_part(id, ',', 1) id1,
    split_part(id, ',', 2) id2,
    split_part(id, ',', 3) id3
from (select '5434980cd70ba0c37d0028, 544976cae79548b16810, 55afdbe672450000a01' id);

          id1           |          id2          |         id3
------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------
 5434980cd70ba0c37d0028 |  544976cae79548b16810 |  55afdbe672450000a01
(1 row)
```